# Save and retrieve options of select element to and from Json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Next is html for text, button ,select elements:

```
<input type="button" id="addNextProjectID" value=" Add next project"/>
<input id="setNewProjectID" type="text" value=" project name "/>
<br>
 <select id="selectProjectID" onfocus="onFocusSelectProject()">
    <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
    <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
 </select>
</br>
```

Code which does add  options to select element from text element on button click

```
function addNextProjectF(){
var x = document.getElementById("selectProjectID");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = document.getElementById("setNewProjectID").value;
option.id = document.getElementById("setNewProjectID").value;
x.appendChild(option);
}
```

How to stringify all options from select and paste them to Json variable and then how to parse them back to select element.

My Select element has first 2 options set from html. I need to keep them.
Here i was thinking that the way would be to loop through the select element options and "append" each option to Json and reversal then to refill select element. But i did not meet any case of code to do this yet. Can you pleas help me with this code?

The case is also that i am not sure also how to use success function from ajax to fill the options of select. Anyway, maybe am  thinking totally wrong approach to get to result i need.So how to proceed?

With next (code below) try i get

> {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}}

empty fields in DB. I presume  "JSON.stringify(saveToprojectsList)" is wrong.

```
function saveToProjectsListF(){
  whichProjectToSave=document.getElementById("selectProjectID").value;
  saveToprojectsList=document.getElementById("selectProjectID");
  var jsonProjectsListToPHP= JSON.stringify(saveToprojectsList);

  console.log(jsonProjectsListToPHP);
   $.ajax({
   method:"POST",
   url: '/wp-content/themes/mypage/PsaveJson.php',
   data: {
     "sendProjectsList":1,
     "whichProjectToSave":whichProjectToSave,
    "jsonProjectsListToPHP":jsonProjectsListToPHP
     },
    success: function(data){
    }
   });
}
```

Comment: There are many Q&A about Ajax, JSON and manipulating the DOM. It is certainly the way to go, but you should first have a go at it, and if you still have a problem, include the code you attempted with and where it went wrong. StackOverflow is not a service for writing your code.

Comment: I added code which fills field in my DB, but the data is wrong. As first i need to see correct data in DB. Then i will go to next step -get data from DB and refill the select element.

Comment: Well you don't want to stringify `saveToprojectsList`, since that is a DOM node. I would answer your question, but there are too many questions packed here... (sending to server, reading from server, updating `select` list, and you have no code for most of these actions). I would suggest your focus on one issue at a time.

Comment: I can do all this stuff with string. The part which i have to learn now is  how to package this string to be able to store and load select element as string.

Comment: `saveToprojectsList` is not a string, nor an object you can stringify.

Comment: I am now considering to make a string array  of options of select element. Actually i have this array now. Next i will try to fill an select element from this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather broad, so I will only focus on the part where you have tried to address it with code, i.e. stringifying the options in the select list.

That code does not work as intended because `saveToprojectsList` is a DOM object, and will just yield an empty object when you try to stringify it to JSON. You can use `map` to extract the text contents of the `option` tags.

NB: As you use jQuery for `$.ajax`, you could use it in other places as well:

```js
function onFocusSelectProject() {}

$('#addNextProjectID').click(function addNextProjectF(){
    var value = $("#setNewProjectID").val();
    $("#selectProjectID").append($("<option>").text(value).attr("id", value));
});

$('#save').click(function saveToProjectsListF(){
    var whichProjectToSave = $("#selectProjectID").val();
    var saveToprojectsList = $.map($("#selectProjectID>option"), function (op) {
        return $(op).text();
    });
    var jsonProjectsListToPHP = JSON.stringify(saveToprojectsList);
    console.log(jsonProjectsListToPHP);
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url: '/wp-content/themes/mypage/PsaveJson.php',
        data: {
            sendProjectsList: 1,
            whichProjectToSave: whichProjectToSave,
            jsonProjectsListToPHP: jsonProjectsListToPHP
        },
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="addNextProjectID" value=" Add next project"/>
<input id="setNewProjectID" type="text" value=" project name "/>
<br>
 <select id="selectProjectID" onfocus="onFocusSelectProject()">
    <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
    <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
 </select>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save"/>
</br>
```